# Is "a factor of K-fold" a idiomatic saying?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning, expressions

This book "Deep Learning and Convolutional Neural Networks for Medical Image Computing" uses an expression "a factor of K-fold".

> As we learned about the current state of research on deep learning, I
>   was surprised to find that other investigators had used convolutional
>   neural networks, one type of deep learning, in the past [22, 23]. But
>   there seemed to be something different about the most recent crop of
>   deep learning algorithms. They routinely used GPU processing to
>   **accelerate training by as much as a factor of 40-fold**. They also used
>   multiple convolution layers and multiple data reduction layers.

It seems that "a factor of 40-fold" means "×40 faster than before".

Is "a factor of K-fold" a idiomatic saying to express this meaning?

Comment: K-fold is very common in computing, though it doesn't seem to be used consistently. It may mean either k times (extension of existing words *twofold* and *threefold*) or k groups, e.g for the latter: "*Each fold is then used once as a validation while the k - 1 remaining folds form the training set*" ([source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html)). However I don't know where this sense comes from, I don't see in dictionaries how *fold* is actually related to *group*, except maybe when talking about a *sheep fold* which is an enclosure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's okay, but a bit redundant.

It is idiomatic to say "It increased 40-fold", or "It increased by a factor of 40". These mean the same, the amount was multiplied by 40. Saying "increased by a factor of 40-fold" mixes these two expressions, which isn't right, but we understand what is meant.

If this is your writing I would suggest editing to tighten the phrasing. If it is someone else then you should be able to understand it.